# Wordpress 3.8 unwanted space beneath images

Tags: html, wordpress, image, whitespace

There's about 3 or 4px white space under all images when viewing a page in wordpress. When viewing the same page without wordpress there's no white space under the same images, despite the same code.

Have tried display block, margin and padding set to 0, and removing empty spaces in the html file, but still for some reason there's this image space. Is this something known with wordpress, such as php code messing something up? I'm using `<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>` + image path for all the images, whereas the original file uses no php and has no image gaps.

Edit: Here are two snapshots from original file and wordpress showing wp's gap.

[image: Original file before wordpress]
[image: Wordpress snapshot showing gap]
Using developer tools I could see that it's the div that holds the images and list items that's responsible for the gap. Yet the other divs holding images and lists in the same way don't have gaps, hm..

Comment: sry, am using wordpress locally,  the image code is inside li tags, like, <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/arrows.gif"></li>

Comment: I'm pretty sure it must be connected to your CSS. Maybe you use a wordpress theme to include your styles and this 'old' CSS is the reason for the white space. It's impossible to help you without seeing the problem, ready to inspect.

Comment: It would depend on what theme you are using, but use firefox or chrome to inspect the css of the image.

Comment: I forgot to mention I did try removing the theme's default css, and only used my own css, yet the space still there. Will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

A quick checklist.. (apologies for it ignoring some of which you stated you've already tried)

- Does the problem appear in both firefox and chrome? If only chrome it's probably a `display: block;` missing somewhere.
- Inspect the element with firefox or chrome to see if wordpress or your theme is inserting any html/css. It may be inserting pre-styled `ul` `li` or `p` tags which you will need to style.
- Make use of !important to override any css that may be set by wordpress core styles. Gallery styling, for example, is still set in core.

!important example usage (with some ideas as to how your theme or wordpress styling could be affecting it from somewhere)

```
display: block !important;
margin: 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
height: 100% !important;
max-height: 100% !important;
vertical-align: top !important;
font-size: 0 !important;
```

- You can also try adding this filter to your functions.php file and then play with the gallery css.

  add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );

Here's a tutorial on styling galleries - http://theme.fm/2011/06/how-to-style-your-wordpress-gallery-43/

There are other filters to remove the auto style inserts by wordpress if you find those are the problem (as it sounds to be)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the gap appears in all firefox, chrome, i.e and opera. Not sure why, since I've tested removing the theme's default css so that it has the same css as the original file that doesn't have image gaps. I'm using a blank theme, so i don't think it has a gallery. In fact checked in the functions file and didn't see one.

Comment: Still not sure what it was, but I just couldn't be bothered with it and just set a specific height on the container element, but as long as it  doesn't break.

Comment: Yea, not worth wasting hours on something you can fix with a less proper method. I had another issue of it myself yesterday and for some reason `vertical-align: top;` fixed it but I forget where in my project that was and what the 'surrounding' circumstances were.